# Does pytest cache function calls?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest that looks as though it is executing an older version of a function and returning a different result than when the function is called.  The function itself for the given string `testing this works` should return `tstng ths wrks`.

```
def remove_vowels(instr):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    _in = instr.lower().split(' ')
    logger.info('_in=%s',_in)   
    out = []
    for word in _in:
        out.append(''.join(x for x in list(word) if x not in vowels))
    return ' '.join(out)
```

When I run this outside of pytest it returns the expected result:

```
inwords = 'testing this works'
expect = 'tstng ths wrks'
print(remove_vowels(inwords))
print(expect)
----------------------------------------------
python .\lib\strutil.py
INFO:__main__:_in=['testing', 'this', 'works']
tstng ths wrks
tstng ths wrks
```

When I run my test for this function through pytest, it looks as though it is executing an older version of it which returned a different result (`testingthisworks`).  It is running in a virtualenv in Windows and I've tried deleting `.pytest_cache`, `.pycache` etc and also running as `pytest --cache-clear`.

```
def test_remove_vowels_multi_word():
    inword = 'testing this works'
    expect = 'tstng ths wrks'
    actual = remove_vowels(inword)
    assert actual == expect
```

The pytest output:

```
   def test_remove_vowels_multi_word():
        inword = 'testing this works'
        expect = 'tstng ths wrks'
        actual = remove_vowels(inword)
>       assert actual == expect
E       AssertionError: assert 'testingthisworks' == 'tstng ths wrks'
E         - tstng ths wrks
E         ?      -   -
E         + testingthisworks
E         ?  +  +    +  +

tests\test_strutil.py:12: AssertionError
```

What am I missing here? I'm using version `6.0.2`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you rename a file?  Try removing `.pyc` that are around

Comment: I have done that and to no avail.  It only returned the correct result after deleting my virtualenv and re-instantiating it.  Ultimately I don't want to have to do that every time I write a function and need to change it during development.  I still have no idea why this is occurring and whether or not it is a bug with Pytest, windows or my IDE (using vscode in this instance).